# images and css are not downloading for iis url rewrite

Tags: asp.net, webforms, url-rewrite-module

i am running my site from VS2013 IDE

i have include country code in url by http module like **http://localhost:53741/gb/**

but there is no folder called gb. so i suppose to get error. just to by pass that error i copy iis url rewrite rule in my web.config file. here it is

```
<rule name="Rewrite rule for Redirecting countries" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="[a-z]{2}/(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/{tolower:{C:1}}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

now the above url works but js and css file not downloaded. i checked with developer tool and js/css files path are ok.

my css is in content folder in root folder and js is in scripts folder. when i check the url of js and css then i found those was ok but files do not downloaded.....do not understand why?

here is developer tool screen shot
[image]

just see the file path from picture above. that is right.

i use this rule

```
<rule name="Some rule">
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.(ashx|axd|css|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|js|flv|f4v)$" negate="true" /> 
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

but still no luck.what causing problem.anyone can help me to figure out this issue. thanks

Comment: For some reason the content type says text/html but should say text/css. Not sure of the cause.

Comment: see my css and js path is ok but still css/js file not loading. i shared the picture.